# How to serialize values which are provided JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL at class level

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml, jackson-databind

Currently my application has a class which is as below

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Employee {
  Department department;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String address;
  String phoneNumber;
}
```

I am capturing the employee object inside the logs where I am converting the object into JSON. I am able to convert the object to JSON but the null values do not get into the JSON.

I have tried the below

```
 objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
 generator.setCodec(objectMapper);
 generator.writeObjectField(fieldName, argument);
```

But not able to get the null values of the fields in JSON. How do I get them?

Comment: I imagine the `@JsonInclude` takes priority.

Comment: Is there anyway I can get nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy an `ObjectMapper` and change some of its options, in this case you can ignore annotations:

```
ObjectMapper mapperIgnoringAnnotations = mapper.copy()
        .disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS)
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
        .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
```

Then use this modified `ObjectMapper` to serialize this class but the standard one for the other classes. Not convenient if `Employee` has many other annotations that you want to take into account.

[USE_ANNOTATIONS](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features#annotation-handling)

Comment: What should be the configuration if it has getters and setters??

Comment: Jackson will look for getters and setters by default for serialising and deserialising respectively. You don't have to include `setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`. If getters/setters are not public then include such setting(s) e.g. with `PropertyAccessor.GETTER`

Comment: OK , Thanks, Can you please provide any ideas on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885668/how-to-overcome-jsonmappingexception, facing JSONMappingexception and StackoverFlow